# Generalised Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms, spectral-sequences, de-rham-cohomology, mayer-vietoris-sequence

In chapter 8 of Bott/Tu, the authors generalise the standard Mayer-Vietoris sequence to the setting of a countable open cover of $X$. Let's fix a countable cover $\{ U_i\}$ of $X$. According to Prop 8.5 of Bott/Tu, the sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow \Omega^*(X) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i} \Omega^*(U_i) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i<j} \Omega^*(U_{ij}) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i<j<k} \Omega^*(U_{ijk}) \rightarrow \cdots  $$
is exact. Later in this chapter they use this sequence to prove some essential properties of the de Rham-Cech bicomplex, and then move into a study of spectral sequences of bicomplexes.

I'm trying to understand this sequence for the simplest case of three covering sets, say $U_1, U_2$ and $U_3$. In this case, the above sequence terminates quickly:

$$ 0 \rightarrow \Omega^*(X) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i} \Omega^*(U_i) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i<j} \Omega^*(U_{ij}) \rightarrow \Omega^*(U_{123}) \rightarrow 0  $$

My question is this: is there a long exact sequence for 3 sets that generalises the usual binary Mayer-Vietoris sequence? A naiive guess would be something like:

$$ \cdots \rightarrow H^q(U_{123})\rightarrow H^{q+1}(X)\rightarrow \bigoplus_i H^{q+1}(U_i) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i<j} H^{q+1}(U_{ij}) \rightarrow H^{q+1}(U_{123}) \rightarrow \cdots $$

Almost all of these maps can be obtained by descending the associated maps that come from the exact sequence of differential forms. I would guess that the connecting homomorphism can be somehow obtained from the associated spectral sequence, but I am not too sure about this.

Comment: No, there isn't such a long exact sequence. In fact, the Mayer Vietoris spectral sequence is all you have. As they explain the in the book, iirc, when you only have two open sets the spectral sequence degenerates to a long exact sequence in the second page. If you have more you're stuck with a spectral sequence for more pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you cover the circle by three intervals that pairwise intersect but not mutually, then $U_{123}$ is empty, $X = S^1$ and $U_i$ are contractible. So you cannot have an exact sequence of the form you guess, as at $H^1(X)$ you'd get
$$0 \to \mathbb{R} \to 0$$
which cannot be exact.

As @Mariano describes in the comments, the Mayer-Vietoris spectral sequence is the right generalization: it reduces to the usual exact sequence if the cover has only $2$ terms.

Alternatively you could also use an iterated exact sequence by first writing down exact sequences for $U_1 \cup U_2$ and $(U_1 \cup U_2) \cap U_3 = U_{13} \cup U_{23}$ and then for $X = (U_1 \cup U_2) \cup U_3$. This is equivalent to the spectral sequence approach, but breaks symmetry between the indices.